# The last position of char in string in R

Tags: r, indexing, charat

I want to ask how can I take the position of last index of char=" | " in R

My string will be similar like below:

I have apple|Orange|banana|perry| in my bag.

Thanks,

Comment: I am having a hard time following your question. Did you want "apple|Orange|banana|perry|" to turn into "apple|Orange|banana|perry"?

Comment: Hi , i have many string and each time i want to retern the last index of char("|") , becuase each time will be deffrent position of char ("|")

Answer (score 3):

One option is `str_locate`

```
library(stringr)
tail(str_locate_all(str1, "[|]")[[1]], 1)
```

With `stringi`, there is a convenient function

```
library(stringi)
stri_locate_last_fixed(str1, '|')
```

#### data

```
str1 <- "I have apple|Orange|banana|perry| in my bag"
```